# Probability of equality of sum

Tags: probability

I have a question about probability. Does the probability of equality of sum depend on number of added elements? In other words, does the probability of equality of sum is greater or smaller if there is more added elements. Added elements are only positive numbers.

x = random positive number (0 - 2^64)

y = a + b + c - where a,b,c are random positive numbers (0 - 2^64)

So what is a probability what x = y?

and E[x] > E[y] or E[x] < E[y] ?

Thanks in advance, pandominox.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer. $\mathbb{E}Z$ may be positive or negative.

Comment: X,Y,Z are positive numbers only.

Comment: If $Z>0$ then $E[Z]>0$ so adding it will increase the sum.

Comment: Okay, the question has been changed.  The original question was about $E[X+Y+Z]$ versus $E[X+Y]$.  There is a difference between probability that two things are equal, and expected value of a random variable.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I have changed the equations.

Comment: Do you have any information about the probability distribution? Are $x, a, b, c$ [iid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) uniform random variables on $[0, 2^{64}]$?

Answer (score 0):

It is approximately $0$. Suppose you consider a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ instead of you discrete distribution. Then 
$$
P(x+y+z = w) = 0 
$$
since $x+y+z=w$ is an hyperplane in a 4-dimensional space with uniform distribution.

In your case you get something which has order $1/2^{64}$ in fact given $a$, $b$, $c$ there exists at most $1$ over $2^{64}$ numbers $y$ such that $y=a+b+c$.

Comment: So,  can I securely assume that $P[x] > P[y]$ or - because these both probabilities are approximately $0$ - more accurate assumption is that $P[x] \approx P[y]$ (or even $P[x] = P[y]$) (sorry, maybe I didn't understand your answer properly)?